# the x lab is not shown complete? how should i set arguments?

Tags: r

```
boxplot(log2(paired_counts+1), las = 2, outline = F, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

how to solve this, does any body know? i'm really new to R

you can reproduce by below code

```
  a <- c("TCGA-38-4625-01A","TCGA-38-4625-11A")
    b <-  data.frame(10120,990)
    colnames(b) <- a
    boxplot(log2(b+1), las = 2, outline = F, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: you can reproduce it now ,please @Limey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a larger bottom (first) margin and plot again, e.g.:

```
par(mar = c(9, 3, 2, 1))  # bottom, left, top, right
boxplot(log2(paired_counts+1), las = 2, outline = F, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

Use a higher value than 9 if the x labels are still not complete.

Comment: Put `opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)` before and `par(opar)` after this to restore defaults.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick solution. Better go to ggplot2, let me know if you need help with it

```r
a <- c("TCGA-38-4625-01A","TCGA-38-4625-11A")
b <-  data.frame(10120,990)
colnames(b) <- a


par(cex.axis=0.5)
boxplot(log2(b+1), las = 2, outline = F, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>